# How to Disable Pseudo localization in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, localization, globalization, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have been playing around with the Multilingual App Toolkit (v4).  I followed the instructions in this article to enable the Pseudo language for testing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I added the 3 registry keys.  Once this was done, i started getting the following warning as part of my build process.

Pseudo localization testing is enabled on this project.  Pseudo can cause certification failures when publishing your app to the store.  Be sure to disable Pseudo before releasing your app.

I have removed the registry settings and rebooted, but i still am getting the warnings.  This is my build machine, and I really need this removed as it appears to be an issue with production releases.

I still want to use the Multilingual App Toolkit for localization, but, I need to disable the Pseudo localization testing on my machine.  How does one remove or disable the testing settings?

thanks in advance for everyone's time,

scot.

Comment: `I added the 3 registry keys.` Just remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was the first thing I tried, followed by a reboot.  I have searched the registry for those 3 values and they do not exist, yet I still get the warnings.

Comment: With such a highly specific question I would try to ask the MAT developers directly, for example via [the MAT blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/).

Answer (score 2):

To disable: in solution Explorer right click ...qps-ploc.xlf, click "exclude from project"

To enable: in solution Explorer click "show all files", right click ...qps-ploc.xlf, click "include in project"

see (@ 4:20) [channel9: Submitting your localized app to the Store](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introducing-Windows-8/Submitting-your-localized-app-to-the-Store)

Ed